# Linker/Inheritance/Virtual function problems

Tags: class, templates, inheritance, linker, virtual

Having trouble inheriting from a template class.
Looks something like this:

```
template<typename type>  
class base {  
protect:  
  ...  
public  
  ...  
  virtual bool func1(type var1);  
};
```

// this class is not templated but derives from template class, don't know if its issue

```
class derived : public base<type_spec_1> {  
protected:  
  ...   
public:  
  ...  
  bool func1(type_spec_1);// function I wish to override;  
};
```

// In the .cpp, I try to scope the function, it compiles but it does not link

```
bool derived::func1(type_spec_1 type){ return false; };
```

The linker gives me an error in this format: LNK2001, unresolved symbol base::func1(type_spec_1);
Like it does not see that `"derived"==base"<type_type_1>"`
How can I provide the proper syntax for this, if it is even possible????

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't you need to do something like this?

```
template<typename type>  
class base {  
protect:  
  ...  
public  
  ...  
  // provide implementation to be overriden
  virtual bool func1(type var1) { return (bool) 0; } 
};
```

Because `class derived : public base<type_spec_1>` says `derived` is derved from a type `base<type_spec_1>`, but the type definition of `base<type_spec_1>` is not completely implemented yet?

Comment: THANKS. That did the trick. I was working on the assumption that virtual functions were abstract until you gave them a definition.

Comment: @Jen: you can write virtual bool func1(type var1) = 0 to have that. Look for "pure virtual methods"

Comment: @jen - good thinking. Why don't you post an answer with an example.

Comment: Compiled! Turns out my method was a bit complicate, i.e. First I had a struct whose parameters depended on the template typenames:
struct{ typename1 Type; };

Then I had a function that returned this "Dynamic" struct, then abstract functions could not be created, they had to be defined!